# Calculating root of number

Tags: javascript

I need to calculate root of number. For example I would like to calculate Pythagorean theorem, so I need to have `z = x*x + y*y;` and then I need to take the square root of z. How can I write that in JavaScript?

Comment: [The JavaScript `Math` object is your friend.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math)

Comment: This has nothing to do with AngularJS.

Comment: Does the result need to be really accurate?

Comment: Yes I need it accurate

Answer (score 4):

You can use the built in js function

```
Math.sqrt(9); // 3
```