# How to perform square root operation?

Tags: javascript, square-root

I would like to calculate distance from origin for some points. I don't know how to do that in Javascript.

If `x` and `y` are the co-ordinates of a point `distanceFromOrigin=sqrt(x^2 + y^2)`.

So far, below is the code I could get running in HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<script id="vertices">
float distanceFromOrigin;

void
main()
{
distanceFromOrigin=(x * x) +(y * y);


}
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

How to add a square root to the above variable distanceFromOrigin. And also is there a power function instead of doing `x*x`?

Comment: See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sqrt) on `Math.sqrt()`.

Comment: Sorry but this question has no research done, please do so before asking. Asking on SO should be more of a last resort.

Comment: Math.sqrt() doesn't work in HTML. Is there anything that I have to import?

Comment: HTML? You mean Javascript I guess...

Comment: No, I have two files. 1 html file and 1 java script file. I want to compute square root in html file

Comment: You can't do that in HTML, just in Javascript.

Comment: Where did you see that syntax?

Comment: It is part of an assignment of an online course

Comment: Your question's code doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating root of number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29606160/calculating-root-of-number)

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lw2ma29n/)

```js
function calculate() {
  var x = document.getElementById("x").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("y").value;
  console.log("Distance from origin to x and y is : " + Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2))));
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="x" placeholder="x">
  <input type="text" id="y" placeholder="y">
  <input type="button" value="Find distance from origin" onclick="calculate();">
</div>
```

Comment: If you need the exact value then remove `Math.round()`

Answer (score -2):

```
Math.sqrt(9); // --> 3
Math.pow(4, 3); // --> 64
```

[W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sqrt.asp)

Comment: I don't hope you are asking me. I don't know. Maybe because it lacks any explanation?